# getJson + Twitter

Tags: php, jquery, api, twitter, getjson

Im not that much into programation but I've been trying to edit a base code one with another ones to display more than 1 tweet but it dosen't work, could anyone help me?

```
 $.getJSON("http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/user.json?count=3&callback=?", 
  function(data) {
      $("#tweet").html(data[0].text);
  });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data` is an array.  So `data[0]` accesses the first tweet returned from twitter.
You need to iterate over the array and append the other tweets to your div.

```
$.getJSON("http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/user.json?count=3&callback=?", 
function(data) {
  $(data).each(function() {
     $("#twitter").append($(document.createElement('div'))
        .html(this.text).addClass('tweet'));
  }
});
```

**Edit**: Changed selector to target `#twitter` div and add a `tweet` class to each tweet.

Comment: Omg this just worked great, tyvm ville, just another question how could I specifiy the div I want to be added, since #tweet is supposed to be the "class" for each tweet, while my container of them is called #twitter

Comment: jQuery selectors that begin with # reference ID's (just like css).  So make your container ID "twitter", not "#twitter".  I'll reflect this in an edit.

Comment: wow seriosuly thank you so much, everything worked perfectly!